# Why git doesn't output the message of my commit?

Tags: git

I did a commit with message to my repo in GitHub.

```
git add --all
git commit -m "my message"
git push
```

After that I run this command to get the message:

```
git log --format="medium" -1 c39d177b60eec4a19ee7f559f66c0e801eadac61 | tail -1
```

I get:

```
 Merge branch 'master' of https://www.github.com/.../...
```

Instead of 
    my message

Why git doesn't output the message of my commit?

**Update**

After I run `git logs` I see my commit below `Merge branch 'master' of ...`, I think git or github add commit when they push to the master.

The problem is I need only the last commit, to be my. so maybe there is a way to push with commit message? or disable the "Merge branch 'master' of .."

Comment: Because there's a merge commit after your commit. Are you the only one with access to the repo?

Comment: not sure. I read the commit message in Jenkins.

Comment: Could you edit the question to reflect that. It's important information. Who was the author of the merge commit? What branches was it merging?

Comment: my user in github

Comment: Is that the credentials that Jenkins uses to do its thing?

Comment: yes I think so..

Comment: So it's just what Jenkins does. It takes your changes, merges them into its testing branch, and runs the build and tests or whatever else you tell it to.

Comment: I can post an answer, but you need to edit the question to provide some details, like which branch you push to vs which one you see the commit on, and that you are using Jenkins. Without that, it sounds like magic that should never happen.